# How to access json_encode result,.?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I've the following array in PHP:

```
$user_data = Array
(
    [session_id] => 30a6cf574ebbdb11154ff134f6ccf4ea
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
    [last_activity] => 1326795168
    [user_id] => 1
    [username] => praditha
    [logged_in] => 1
    [user_status] => 1
    [email] => xxx@yyy.com
)
```

and then in javaScript, I encode that array to json using:

```
var userData = '<?php echo json_encode($user_data); ?>';
```

and I using firebug to see userData value and this is the result:

```
"{"session_id":"30a6cf574ebbdb11154ff134f6ccf4ea","ip_address":"127.0.0.1","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1","last_activity":1326795168,"user_id":"1","username":"praditha","logged_in":true,"user_status":"1","email":"xxx@yyy.com"}"
```

and the question is how di I access the array of `userData` ?
For example I wanna get the `username` of the `userData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you wrapped your `json_encode` output in quotes, `$userData` is a string instead of an object. Losing the quotes will create a Javascript object:

```
var userData = <?php echo json_encode($user_data); ?>;
alert(userData.username);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
userData.session_id;
userData.ip_appress;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote it. Just

```
var userData = <?php echo json_encode($user_data); ?>;
```

then you can access `userData.session_id` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remove the quotes around the string in Javascript. So change:

```
var userData = '<?php echo json_encode($user_data); ?>';
```

to:

```
var userData = <?php echo json_encode($user_data); ?>;
```

`josn_encode()` outputs a Javascript object literal, so it is valid Javascript code. By surrounding it with quotes you simply populate a string with this data, but if you remove them it will work.

Answer (score 1):

use it as

```
<?php
$data = array('index1'=>'value1','index2'=>'value2');
?>
<script>
    var json_data = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
    alert(json_data['index1']);
    alert(json_data['index2']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DIV id="test"><?echo json_encode($_POST);?></div>



<div id="ajax">

</div>

<script>
var sample=$("#test").text();
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(sample);
$("#ajax").load("ceva.php",obj);

</script>
```

Just a script I used to get data from a div and send it to a script using $_POST. Use jQuery